# ERR! next-test@0.1.0 build: `next build` JEST and Next.js

Tags: webpack, jestjs, next.js, config

Ever since I added jest and react testing library to my project I can seem to be able to deploy my Next.js project to Vercel. If anyone could help that would be great!

Not used to configs so not sure what to do. I've had a look around the web but there doesn't seem to be an answer that has worked for me.

My error:

```
16:48:25.726    > Build error occurred
16:48:25.728    ReferenceError: expect is not defined
16:48:25.728        at Object.<anonymous> (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/@testing-library/jest-dom/dist/extend-expect.js:7:1)
16:48:25.728        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
16:48:25.728        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
16:48:25.728        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
16:48:25.728        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
16:48:25.728        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
16:48:25.728        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
16:48:25.728        at Object.<anonymous> (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/@testing-library/jest-dom/dist/index.js:3:1)
16:48:25.728        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
16:48:25.729        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10) {
16:48:25.729      type: 'ReferenceError'
16:48:25.729    }
16:48:25.746    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
16:48:25.746    npm ERR! errno 1
16:48:25.749    npm ERR! next-test@0.1.0 build: `next build`
16:48:25.749    npm ERR! Exit status 1
16:48:25.749    npm ERR! 
16:48:25.749    npm ERR! Failed at the next-test@0.1.0 build script.
16:48:25.749    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
16:48:25.756    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
16:48:25.756    npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2021-04-25T15_48_25_750Z-debug.log
16:48:25.760    Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
16:48:28.418    Done with "package.json"
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "next-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@lottiefiles/react-lottie-player": "^3.1.2",
    "next": "10.1.3",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-mailchimp-subscribe": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    }
  }
}
```

next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  webpack(config) {
    config.node = { fs: "empty" };
    return config;
  },
};
```

Comment: This means that a test is loaded in production, this shouldn't happen. Make sure there are no tests in `pages` for starters.

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks! Forgot to remove them!